# Create a loop with dynamic vars

Tags: c#, linq, razor

I use a 2sxc (DNN module) view to create some statistics for a questionnaire (kind of survey with y/n questions mostly).

I get the data with:

```
var items = AsDynamic(App.Data["entity_name"]);
```

And I can easily get the counts with linq, but I want to ask if there is a better way to just loop through all the possible questions (it's a fixed list with "upa1", "upa2", "upb1", "upb2", etc) instead of just writing them all. Or if there is globally a better way to make these counts.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>QuestionID</td>
        <td>Question description</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>No</td>
        <td>N/a</td>
        <td>Indicator %</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td>upa1</td>
        <td>This is upa1</td>
        <td>@items.Count(i => i.upa1 == "y")</td>
        <td>@items.Count(i => i.upa1 == "n")</td>
        <td>@items.Count(i => i.upa1=="na")</td>
        <td>@(((decimal)items.Count(i => i.upa1 == "y") * 100 / items.Count(i => i.upa1 == "s" || i.upa1 == "n")
        ).ToString( "0.0" ))%</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td>upa2</td>
        <td>This is upa2</td>
        <td>@items.Count(i => i.upa2 == "y")</td>
        <td>@items.Count(i => i.upa2 == "n")</td>
        <td>@items.Count(i => i.upa2=="na")</td>
        <td>@(((decimal)items.Count(i => i.upa2 == "y") * 100 / items.Count(i => i.upa2 == "s" || i.upa2 == "n")
        ).ToString( "0.0" ))%</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td>upb1</td>
        <td>This is upb1</td>
        <td>@items.Count(i => i.upb1 == "y")</td>
        <td>@items.Count(i => i.upb1 == "n")</td>
        <td>@items.Count(i => i.upb1=="na")</td>
        <td>@(((decimal)items.Count(i => i.upb1 == "y") * 100 / items.Count(i => i.upb1 == "s" || i.upb1 == "n")
        ).ToString( "0.0" ))%</td>
    <tr>
    (...)
</table>
```

Comment: You shouldn't have all these separate properties "upa1", "upa2", "upb1", "upb2", etc, but *one* property (like "Type") that contains the *values* "upa1", "upa2", "upb1", "upb2", etc. Then you can easily group the data and build a lookup dictionary containing the counts.

Comment: Care to show me an example?

Comment: Well, probably just something like a class having properties `Type` (values "upa1", etc.) and `Answer` (values "y", etc.). As a bonus, you can built the table in a simple `@foreach` loop instead of all these repetitive `<tr>`s.

Comment: View-only solution. No controller. Also, I truly don't understand what you are talking about (non-programmer with 1 month of c# experience)

Comment: If you attempted to use the code I posted in one of your other questions(but that has to do with this one obviously), than you would be able to loop through the Dictionary and you would end up with only one definition of HTML row. Please look into my answer on your other question.

Comment: Can you create those classes without customizing the controller?

Comment: @Rob I see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46773098/861716) you refer to. Clearly it should be something like that, but seemingly João should follow a decent C# programming course first.

Comment: :) That is true. And not just C#. I am a nurse, just using these small page views for research projects. However, I am not even sure 2sxc supports custom classes (as in user created classes - I will ask the dev team).